# How can I calculate the raster counts within an overlapping polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster with land use classes (see image). I want to count the pixel values (i.e. the classes) within the blue perimeter. In QGIS, there is a tool called 'Raster layer unique values report' which can be used to count pixel values. However, it is not possible to select a vector layer to only count the unique values within a specific polygon. As such, I get the pixel counts for the entire raster.

Is it possible to only count the pixel values from a raster within a polygon in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Zonal Histogram tool`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-histogram) using a polygon layer as input will give a new version of the polygon layer with a column for each raster value containing its count

[image]

Alternatively, you can use PyQGIS to clip the raster by the mask polygon, and then access the pixel counts through its data provider:

```py
poly = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my polygon')[0]

rast = 'path/to/raster'

## clip raster to polygon
rast_clipped = processing.run("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer", {'INPUT':rast,'MASK':poly,'SOURCE_CRS':None,'TARGET_CRS':None,'NODATA':None,'ALPHA_BAND':False,'CROP_TO_CUTLINE':True,'KEEP_RESOLUTION':False,'SET_RESOLUTION':False,'X_RESOLUTION':None,'Y_RESOLUTION':None,'MULTITHREADING':False,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':0,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':'C:/temp/myClippedRaster.tif'})['OUTPUT']

## make a layer from the clipped raster path
rast_clipped = QgsRasterLayer(rast_clipped, 'rast_clipped')

## get the extent of the layer
extent = rast_clipped.extent()

## access the data provider
prov = rast_clipped.dataProvider()

## get histogram from data provider
## bin count 0 means it will create the most appropriate number of bins, minimum and maximum are the limits of the raster values you wish to count
hist = prov.histogram(bandNo=1, binCount=0, minimum=1, maximum=7, extent=extent, sampleSize=0, includeOutOfRange=False, feedback=None)

## get list of counts corresponding with bins (for a categorical raster these correspond with an ordered list of the class values)
counts = hist.histogramVector

print(counts)

> [2893, 46778, 21800, 4, 0, 245943, 26932]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Zonal histogram:

> This algorithm appends fields representing counts of each unique value
> from a raster layer contained within zones defined as polygons.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try the ["Zonal statistics"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-statistics) geoalgorithm:

> This algorithm calculates statistics of a raster layer for each
> feature of an overlapping polygon vector layer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, with the "Zonal statistics" tool I cannot count *unique* raster values, can I?

Comment: A good question! I do not know for now